# Python: Visualisation of waves

Tags: python, visualization, physics, wave

I want to programm an easy visualisation of wave propagation. 
I tried this with visual python (VPython) but the programm is very slow.
I want to use a 2-D visualisation now. 
Which module could you recommend?
Tkinter? Matplotlib?

For the computation i use numpy/scipy because it is fast.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Do you think matplotlib is a good choice? It looks very strong.

EDIT: I really get stuck. Please help me!

Comment: What kind of visualization? Is it like http://www.falstad.com/membrane/j2/ What part of the program is slow? Have you measured it? Try http://pygame.org It uses NumPy as the default package for surfarray/sndarray

Comment: For example, see 2D Waves program at http://www.geometrian.com/Programs.php

Comment: http://www.pygame.org/pcr/water/index.php This looks good, but I cant install Numeric (always problems with dependencies :( ) , so I cant use this.

Comment: `pygame` itself uses `numpy` by default. Converting `pygame-water` from `Numeric` to `numpy` might be as simple as: `s/from Numeric import/from numpy import/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this library:
http://linux.wareseeker.com/Programming/summon-1.8.8.zip/2911b4d847

Python Imaging Library is supposed to be good for 2D graphics:
http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Other Useful Links:
Boost.Python http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/
PyOpenGL http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/

These link's have some good information on them.

I'm not familar with matplotlib but it's got some good review's:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/reviews/

Comment: I cant install summon on Python 2.6. vsvarsall.bat is missing (?)

Comment: I didn't find a refresh function for pictures in the PIL-module.

Comment: Sorry but I think PIL doesn't refreshes the pictures. I wrote above that I want to show wave propagation and not a standing wave. I try to find a solution for many hours now. But nothing works.

Comment: @kame - That indicates that it is trying to run Visual Studio to compile some C code. See if your can get a prebuilt version, install Visual Studio (There's a free version) or see if you can find the options to compile with the MINGW compiler. Try Stackoverflow for questions like this!